# Sending object via $.post

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, object, post

I have an object saved in the variable called items.

```
0: Object
    name: "Jim"
         age: "42"
 1: Object
    name: "Bill"
        age: "50"
```

When trying to post

```
$.post("mypage.php", items, function(data)
```

I get an empty post variable in the php page, but  this returns post variables

```
$.post("mypage.php", "name=jim", function(data)
```

What am I doing wrong?

**Edit** it is an array of objects so if I pass

```
$.post( "mypage", items[0], function( data) {
```

I get a results but

**$.post( "mypage", items, function( data) {**

print_r is empty

Comment: Can you please post the code of your *actual* object. Also, just FYI there's no such thing as a 'jQuery object', it's just an object.

Comment: Look at your browser's developer tools. Look at the Net tab. Is the request being made? Does it get a response? Do they contain the data you expect?

Comment: search for JSON.stringify !

Comment: @kasperTaeymans theres no need, jQuery does it for you automatically when you provide an object to any of the AJAX functions.

Comment: ohh, okay! didn't know that... always using stringify.

Comment: Note that it looks like `items` is an array containing objects, and you wouldn't neccessarely get `$_POST["Bill"]` in PHP, so you did of course dump $_POST or `print_r` it to see the actual values it contains.

Comment: You should `var_dump($_POST);` on `mypage.php` to see what's in the POST body.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the object you're posting may be an array with this format:

```
items = [
    {
        name: "Jim",
        age: "42"
    },
    {
        name: "Bill",
        age: "50"
    }
]
```

The [docs](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/#jQuery-post-url-data-success-dataType) seem to indicate that you must pass a plain object. You probably want to post something with the format:

```
items = {
    people: [
        {
            name: "Jim",
            age: "42"
        },
        {
            name: "Bill",
            age: "50"
        }
    ]
};
```

Then you should be able to access the data via `$_POST['people']`.

## UPDATE

To be accurate, you can post your array just fine, it will generate this post `Jim=&Bill=`

Almost surely not what you want. However if you follow the syntax specified by [jQuery.param](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.param/), your array will be treated correctly. Should be and array of objects with name and value:

```
items = [
    {
        name: "Jim",
        value: "42"
    },
    {
        name: "Bill",
        value: "50"
    }
]
```

Comment: I am sure this is right and will mark it as correct but I ended up using $.ajax with no problems. Ross

Comment: Actually it's wrong, jQuery accepts arrays just fine, even if the keys aren't preserved as name/value pairs.

Comment: jQuery can handle the array, but it won't behave as the OP is expecting.

Answer (score 0):

You are using a curious behaviour of jQuery. It's found in the `$.param` function, which is used behind the scenes to prepare an AJAX query from your data.

If you send an array, jQuery expects it to be an array of objects, each of which has two keys, `name` and `value`. You are obviously not providing data in that structure. Your script actually sends data that looks like this:

```
Jim=undefined&Bill=undefined
```

If you do `print_r($_POST['Jim']);` in PHP, you will get the string `undefined`.

You obviously don't want this. You need to send the array within an object.

```
{
  people: [
    {
      name: 'Jim', 
      age: 42
    }, 
    {
      name: 'Bill',
      age: '50'
    }
  ]
}
```

This way your data will be serialised as this:

```
people[0][name]=Jim&people[0][value]=42&people[1][name]=Bill&people[1][age]=50
```

If you do `print_r($_POST['people']);`, you will get a meaningful result.